# Adding checkbox with postback dynamically in gridview column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic, checkbox

I'm trying to create a gridview with dynamic columns, this columns consist of checkbox, the checkbox must be able to trigger an onchange event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
LoadTable();
}
```

LoadTables() - Creates column dynamically according to the list of modules the user subscribes to.

```
private void LoadTable()
{
    List<Module> ListModule = getModules(UserID);
    foreach (Module m in ListModule)
    {
        TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
        tfield.HeaderText = m.ModuleName;
        gv.Columns.Add(tfield);
    }
    gv.DataBind();
}
```

OnTheRowBound, a checkbox is created and added into the table. How do i add the trigger event for the checkbox?

```
protected void OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        List<Module> ListModule = getModules(UserID);
        int i = 2; // cell postioning
        foreach (Module m in ListModule)
        {
            CheckBox cbActive = new CheckBox();
            cbActive.ID = m.ModuleIDs;
            cbActive.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean((e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView).Row["isActive"].ToString());
            //How do i add an onCheckChanged event to trigger whenever the checkbox value is changed?
            //Something like: cbActive.CheckedChanged =  "SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged"
            cbActive.AutoPostBack = true;
            e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(cbActive);
            i++;
        }
    }
}


protected void SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Update Database. 
}
```

Am i doing it wrongly? Is there a better way to create this functionality?

Comment: It looks ok as far as it is working. Do you have any problems? You can register the event using cbActive.CheckedChanged += SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged;

Comment: Alright man it worked! can you answer the question so i can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just posting this as answer instead of comments

You can register the event using the following code

```
cbActive.CheckedChanged += SelectCheckBox_OnCheckedChanged
```

The other part should be fine as far as it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cbActive.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(cbActive_CheckedChanged);
```

Handler:

```
protected void cbActive_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //your code here...
}
```